# Which door do you take?

Tags: logical-deduction

You walk into a house with the owner of the house. It has no electricity what so ever. He locks the door behind you. You are stuck. You see two doors, **Red** and **Green**. Which door do you take?

Comment: I think you're missing some of the riddle, it looks like the mansion of death riddle: You are stuck. You see two doors, Red and Green: Pick one. Now you see a purple door and a orange door. Pick one. Now you see a door with a golden handle and a door with a silver handle. Pick one. You finally come to some signs on three doors. One says “Death from drowning,” another says “Death from machine guns,” and the last one says “Death from electric chair.” Then you see a big sign off to the side that says “Or stay in the mansion and starve to death.” What do you choose and still live?

Comment: The lack of electricity must have some significance, but I am not sure what, at the moment.

Comment: Based on the varied responses, it seems unlikely that an answer can be arrived at through logical deduction (as implied by the tag).  This question is in danger of being closed as *too broad* without a more rigorous definition of the puzzle or an explanation of how it can be logically solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a trick question, since:

> You know one of the doors is locked

So:

> You take whichever door is not locked, obviously

Answer (score 1):

I would take:

> whichever door the owner takes, as he walked in with you.

Answer (score 1):

I think

> You take the door in front of you because he locked the door behind you. The color of the doors shouldn't matter because there is no electricity in the house.

Comment: Technicality - there may not be a door in front of you - it might be to the side or behind you as well.

Answer (score 1):

> You don't need a key to unlock a door from the inside. Just as easily as the owner locked the door from the inside, I would unlock the door that I entered from and leave.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the door labeled as

> green
> because green means go, and red means stop.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps, I would choose the door labelled as

> **red** ,

As,

> when it is read upside down, can look like *pal* (a friend). Though not through the typed words, in a cursive hand writing style it can fairly look so!